# Подключить шрифт ко всему приложению

Tags: android, style

Подключил шрифт через библиотеку [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)
Могу настроить его на отдельные элементы, кнопки, текст вью. 
Нужно установить его по умолчанию в тему приложения
1.Переопределил шрифт  в стиле, но ничего не поменялось, что не так ?
2. Как добавить дополнительный шрифт через эту библиотеку?

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.TextView</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Widget"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Widget.TextView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/FiraSansCondensed.ttf</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.FontPath" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/FiraSansCondensed.ttf</item>
    </style>


    <style name="TextViewCustomFont">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/FiraSansCondensed.ttf</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```